# z-index on table tr above global overlay

Tags: css, html-table, z-index

I want position a specific tr from a table above a global overlay. 
I tried this code without success :

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr class="tr-1">
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>  
  <tr class="tr-2">
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
tr {
  background-color: white;
}

tr.tr-1 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 20;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .3;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Any idea?

This is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwsxd55o/)

This is the expected result:

[image]

Comment: @splitfire378 Can you share the expected output and more details on the problem you are facing?

Comment: Is there any reason your `.tr-1` needs a higher `z-index` than your `.overlay` ?

Comment: @Scoots Isn't it obvious?

Comment: I edited my message with the desired result

Comment: are you wanting it centered in the overlay?

Comment: @ProEvilz A poorly phrased comment. For me in Firefox it was above the overlay in the fiddle, so I meant to ask what the actual problem was and derped a bit.

Comment: Applying `position:relative; z-index:20` to the table cell instead of the table row (i.e. for `tr.tr-1 td` instead of just `tr.tr-1`) seems to work in Chrome. Probably it's because table row box is too `virtual` and some browsers don't create real box for it (it's not against the spec since the effect of `position:relative` on the table parts is "undefined"). But table cells are real CSS boxes and should obey `position` and `z-index`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `display` property to `block` on your `tr` will make the layer come above the overlay.

```css
tr {
  background-color: white;
}

tr.tr-1 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 20;
  display:block;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  display:block;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="tr-1">
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>  
  <tr class="tr-2">
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Thx a lot @ProEvitz, you save my day!

Comment: Can someone explain what is happening?

Comment: Np, I found this out by playing with the CSS. It would be great if a more technical CSS genius could add some explanation as to why this solution works instead of just changing the `z-index`

Comment: Please note that doing so effectively makes the `tr` not a table row anymore. It could result in unexpected changes if the table has more than one column.

Comment: Making a tr block will remove its table-row property and as a result, the display will become distorted. @AshleyBrown, can you suggest any solution here..

Comment: Found a solution here, instead of 'tr' giving a z-index and all other required porperties to nested 'td' will solve the problem.